# Rewrite url for subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am rewriting my urls with this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

# REDIRECT MAIN DOMAIN
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.nl$
# /subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www.domain.nl/
# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.domain.nl/$1
# site
# subfolder/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.nl$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www.domain.nl/ [L]



# SUBDOMAINS to /sub.domain.nl/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/%1.domain.nl/$1 [P,L]
```

This will take subdomains to there subfolder. So x.domain.nl goes to domain.nl/x.domain.nl.
However, this also shows as [SCRIPT_URI] => http://domain.nl/x.domain.nl/
Is it possible that all the $_SERVER variables show just x.domain.nl on all the variables and not the long version?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not following your question. The `$_SERVER` variable is designed to give you certain information about the request. So no you can't change the behavior of `SCRIPT_URI` or `REQUEST_URI`. If you don't want the URI attached just use `HTTP_HOST` to get the hostname.

Comment: Yes, I can use the HTTP_HOST. BUT certain installations such as Wordpress use other variables and the complete system/website doesn't work and use the wrong one. So I want the browser to think that it is on the subdomain and not in the folder where the files are actually situated. Is this possible?

Comment: The SERVER_NAME or HTTP_HOST should be the name of the domain not the URI. So it should give you the subdomain name. Those vars have been that way and wordpress works fine for most people. Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to forward subdomains to subfolders. And I want the browser to think that it is on the subdomain and not in the subfolder. Do you get what I mean?